On Stop Loss strategy.exit, Profit Target strategy.exit order is left on the table
I've tried probably every tweak to get around this problem.
I'm creating 'enter_long', 'pt_long' and 'exit_long' orders. I've set to exit 75% of the position if the Profit Target price is reached.
strategy.entry("enter_long", strategy.long, stop = 
strategy.exit("pt_long", qty_percent = pt_exit_amount_percent, limit = long_profit_target_price)
strategy.exit("exit_long", stop = long_exit_price)

Here is an example of the order


white line is order entry price
red line is order Stop Loss price
blue line is order Profit Target price

As you can see, Profit Target price is never hit, but exit_long does not close the whole position. 75% of the position is still left on the table. Why?
Thank you for your time and help.

I solved the issue using strategy.order and oca group
strategy.entry("enter_long", strategy.long, stop = long_entry_price)
pt_amount = strategy.default_entry_qty(long_entry_price) * pt_exit_amount_percent / 100
strategy.order("pt_long", strategy.short, oca_name = "bracket", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce, qty = pt_amount, limit = long_profit_target_price)
strategy.exit("exit_long", oca_name = "bracket", stop = long_exit_price)

Issue I was encountering is described in the documentation
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#strategy-exit

It’s important to note that orders produced by this command reserve a
portion of the open market position to exit. strategy.exit() cannot
place an order to exit a portion of the position already reserved for
exit by another exit command.

